# Wrap provider in main

Tags: flutter

Any help
I have an error on the
wrapping provider on the main.

the error is on the :

```
create: (context) => LocaleProvider(),
```

this is my code :

```
  import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:trying_localisations_app/provider/locale_provider.dart';
import 'support_locale.dart';

ChangeNotifierProvider(
create: (context) => LocaleProvider(),
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Consumer<LocaleProvider>(
      builder: (context, provider, child) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          localizationsDelegates: const [
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate
          ],
          locale: provider.locale,
          supportedLocales: L10n.support,
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily),
            builder: LoadingScreen.init(),
            routes: {
              HomePage.page: (_) => const HomePage()
            }
          );
        }
      );
    }
  )
```

PS : i follow https://medium.com/@echolaojue/how-to-make-l10n-with-flutter-fd61e21e61d8

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
create: (context) => LocaleProvider(),
```

Comment: When i do :
`create: (context) => LocaleProvider(),`
it gaves me full page error

Comment: What error is that?